# FSB, RAM MHz, MT/s, memory divider 1:1, Core2Duo

Tags: memory, cpu, clock

Due to temp (hopefully) financial problems I have to use old laptop. It's FSB (Front Side Bridge) clock is 333**MHz** (https://www.techsiting.com/mt-s-vs-mhz/). It has 2 SO-DIMM slots for DDR2 SDRAM. It had only 1 DIMM 2 Gb previously and it was a nightmare.

Each slot can handle maximum 2Gb so maximum amount of memory is 4Gb. Knowing that supported DDR stands for double data ratio, I've bought for funny money (10 euro) 2 DDR2 DIMM SO-DIMM 800**MHz** hoping to get (assuming memory divider is **1:2** - it's a **double data** ratio, isn't it?) 2x333**MHz**->apply divider=667**MT/s** (no idea how they have avoided 666). As I have Core2**Duo** I even had a very little hope to get 4x333**MHz**=1333**MT/s**.

But it seems that my memory divider is **1:1**, so I get either

- 2x333**MHz**xDivider=333**MT/s**
- 4x333**MHz**xDivider=?

And utilities like *lshw* and *dmidecode* seem to confirm that:

```
~ >>> sudo lshw -C memory | grep clock                                   
          clock: 333MHz (3.0ns) # notice 333MHz here
          clock: 333MHz (3.0ns) # notice 333MHz here
~ >>> sudo dmidecode --type memory | grep Speed                                
    Supported Speeds:
    Current Speed: Unknown
    Current Speed: Unknown
    Speed: 333 MT/s # notice 333MT/s here
    Speed: 333 MT/s # notice 333MT/s here
~ >>>
```

So my 333**MHz** on FSB has been multiplied by 1 (one) and I've got 333**MT/s** (if I understood correct). I'm still satisfied: OS does not swap that much, boot process is faster, programs starts faster, browser does not hang every hour and I can open much more tabs). I just want to know, since I have Core2**Duo** what **MT/s8*8 do I have from these two? Or maybe it is even more comlicated?

- 2x333**MHz**xDivider=333**MT/s**
- 4x333**MHz**xDivider=667**MT/s** # 4 because of **Duo**

and is there any difference for 2 processors system with just 4Gb of RAM with **MT\s** == **MHz**?

PS BIOS is old (although latest) and I cannot see real FSB clock there, nor change it nor change the memory divider.

Comment: Looks like the guy from the shop with used stuff f.. me up a bit and sold DDR2 333MHz as DDR2x800MHz, but i'm not much offended as for both he wanted only 10 euro.

Anyway this is strange

Comment: But still this is strange: This is double data rate so MT/s should've been 2x333=667, but it is 333. 
 
sudo lshw -C memory


```
~ >>>  sudo lshw -C memory | grep "DDR2\|clock"                                                                                                                     [1]
          description: SODIMM DDR2 Synchronous 333 MHz (3.0 ns)
          clock: 333MHz (3.0ns)
          description: SODIMM DDR2 Synchronous 333 MHz (3.0 ns)
          clock: 333MHz (3.0ns)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's no point in checking I/O bus clock using some Linux command/tool because it is just always half of memory clock.

if what is written in electronics.stackexchange.com/a/424928:

```
I/O bus clock is always half of bus data rate.
```

my old machine has these parameters:

- It is DDR2-333 (not standardized by  JEDEC since they start from DDR-400)
- It has memory MHz = 333
- It has memory MT/s = 333
- It has I/O bus MHz = 166.5 # just because

The thing I still don't get is that I have Core2Duo, so is my memory MT/s = 333 or 666.